# Проблема с функцией bloginfo

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня вот такая проблема с этой функцией:
Переношу сайт с http на https. Естественно, сделал дамб базы, поменял линки. Также и в теме все статические линки поменял. Запускаю сайт уже через https, а вся статика (цсс, скрипты и т.д.) не подгрузилась, так как вызывается через `bloginfo('template_url')` и эта функция вывела линк с http.

Подскажите, плз, где поменять нужно, чтоб норм выводило?

Comment: Обновить в `wp_options` записи с `option_name` = `home` и `siteurl`.

Comment: @Etki и там, и там https. Говорю же - в дампе автозаменой все изменил и перезалил базу.

Answer (score 0):

Из опыта, лутше замените на `bloginfo('template_url')` на `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` .

Так как:

`bloginfo('template_url')` исполняет `get_template_directory_uri()`, которая в свою очередь зовет `get_theme_root_uri()`, а она работает на основе опции `siteurl`. Перед заменой, можете на всякий случай перепроверить таблицу `wp_options`, обновить пермалинки, попробывать отключить и включить снова тему, делая все это под анонимным окном в браузере, вдруг кеш.
Также, если не хотите лезть в код, можно установить настроить плагин https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/ . Тогда не только тема, а и все реурсы будут подгружатся только через https.